# Divide a single row by the entire columns sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to divide a single rows value (units in my case) by the entire rows sum to get a percent (the units column). Can someone help me with this? Below is the code and the data result for the code.

```
    select db.ManufAbbrName Manufacturer, 
       db.ProdName ProductName,
       sum(wk.Units) Units,
       wk.RecordDate RecordDate
  from MDDB db
  join wkdata wk 
    on db.NDC = wk.NDC11 
  join @NDCs nd
    on nd.NDCs = wk.NDC11
 where wk.RecordDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by db.ManufAbbrName,
         db.ProdName,
         wk.RecordDate
```

Results set:

```
Example1    CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE EMO   264475  2013-11-01 00:00:00.000
Example2    CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE       187371  2013-11-01 00:00:00.000
Example3    OLUX-E                      82154   2013-11-01 00:00:00.000
```

So I need to get the percentage values of column 3 for each of the manufacutrers in row 1. So for the first one, 264475 / 534000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the `OVER` clause. [Here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-sever-2005-using-over-with-aggregate-functions) is an article about it

A small example

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (group_id CHAR(1), value INT)

INSERT INTO @t (group_id, value)
VALUES ('A', 5),('A', 5), ('A', 5),('B', 5),('B', 5)

SELECT group_id, value, group_total, rate = CASE WHEN group_total = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (1.0*value) / (1.0*group_total) END
FROM (
    SELECT group_id, value, group_total = SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY group_id)
    FROM @t
) t
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, can you put more than one value in the partition fuction?

Comment: @user1049984 Yes just list `PARTITION BY Col1, Col2`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `SUM(y) OVER(Partition By x)` usage.
You could do the following:

```
SELECT group_id
, value
, SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY group_id)
, CASE WHEN SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY group_id) = 0 THEN 0 
ELSE (1.0*value) / (1.0*SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY group_id)) END as Rate

FROM t
```

**[SQLFiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71b31/3)